# Pass route to component, React and Express

Tags: reactjs, express

Given this route:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = new Router()

const staticPages = [
  'privacy',
  'terms'
]

staticPages.forEach(page => {
  router.get(`/${page}`, (req, res) => {
    res.render('base', { bundle: 'static' })
  })
})

export default router
```

I need to dynamically build a component that uses the route `${page}` to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` from a `.pug` file. This is what my page that calls the component looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Page from 'app/components/base-page'
import Static from 'app/components/static'

let page = 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page >
    <Static content={this.route} />
  </Page>,
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

The parameter `content={this.route}` needs to be pulled from the route controller and match `${page}` so that the component `<Static content={this.route} />` knows which `.pug` file to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` from. How can this be done?

**Edit:** For clarification, the component itself would look something like this..

```
export default class Static extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({
      __html: ''
    })

    let page = '/content/terms'

    got({page})
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
        return resp
      })
      .then(content => {
        this.setState({
          __html: content
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state} />
    )
  }
}
```

I've also added another route to the terms.html:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = new Router()

const staticPages = [
  'privacy',
  'terms'
]

staticPages.forEach(page => {
  router.get(`/content/${page}`, (req, res) => {
    res.send(`content/${page}.html`)
    console.log(req, res)
  })
})

export default router
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you post the code for `Static`? Can't help without seeing how you intend on this working.

Comment: Updated the question with some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using 2 different express routers like this:

static-content.js

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = new Router()

const staticPages = [
  'privacy',
  'terms'
]

staticPages.forEach(page => {
  router.get(`/content/${page}`, function (req, res) {
    res.render(`content/${page}`, function (err, html) {
      console.log(err)
      res.send(html)
    })
  })
})

export default router
```

static.js

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = new Router()

const staticPages = [
  'privacy',
  'terms'
]

staticPages.forEach(page => {
  router.get(`/${page}`, (req, res) => {
    res.render('base', { bundle: 'static' })
  })
})

export default router
```

Here's the page and component jsx:

static-page.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Page from 'app/components/base-page'
import Static from 'app/components/static'

let page = document.location.pathname

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page >
    <Static content={page} />
  </Page>,
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

static-component.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import got from 'got'

export default class Static extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({
      __html: ''
    })

    let page = '/content' + this.props.content

    got(page)
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.body
      })
      .then(content => {
        this.setState({
          __html: content
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state} />
    )
  }
}
```